# Mathematica Typing Effect

Tags: dynamic, string-manipulation

[Here](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsTypewriter/index.html) is a Typing Effect in javascript.

I could only implement a very simple one:

```
DynamicModule[{s = ""},
 Dynamic[Refresh[
   If[Length[s] > 10, s = "", s = s <> "x"],
   TrackedSymbols :> {}, UpdateInterval -> 0.5]]]
```

How can I do that exactly the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps

```
typingEffect[str_String, secPerLetter_: 0.3] := 
 Dynamic[StringTake[str, 
   Clock[{0, StringLength@str, 1}, StringLength@str secPerLetter]]]
```

(thanks @SjoerdC.deVries)

So this gives an animation

```
typingEffect["hello my dear"]
```

Other effects can be implemented with the same idea, such as

```
typingEffect2[str_String] := 
 Row@MapIndexed[
   Style[#, 
      FontColor->Dynamic@ColorData["Rainbow"][
       Mod[(First@#2 - 0.5)/StringLength@str + Clock[], 1]]] &, 
   Characters@str]
```

Comment: as would my 3 years old son say: "but why?" ;-)

Comment: @chris, I wouldn't know exactly what to explain to your 3 year old son :P. What part does he not understand?

Comment: well that's the thing: it doesn't matter what I explain to him... He always comes up with that question!

Comment: @chris, don't worry, he'll soon grow up like all of us and forget he never got his answer

Comment: @Rojo, typing `StringLength@str/.slen_:>` and then `slen` twice takes just as many characters as simply typing `StringLength@str` twice, but is perhaps more confusing.

Comment: @VF1, it's a habit to tr to make it calculate all stuff only once. I'll edit for clarity

Comment: @Rojo That makes sense.  Just wondering, though: Is using `ReplaceAll` like you have more efficient than making a `Module` variable, then re-using that value?

Comment: @VF1, in this case I doubt any of both are more efficient than running StringLength twice, though it's still better style to reduce the redundancies, the places where you should change the code if you want to change something

Comment: @VF1, in general, my guess (haven't tried) is that using `ReplaceAll` like that should be a bit faster than `Module` but it also should be irrelevant. I find it neater to go "building up" my constants, since I don't need to nest extra brackets. In any case, if you are going to use `Module` on constants, use `With` instead

Comment: The `Clock` statement can be slightly improved by adding an integer 1 as step size (no `Round` necessary anymore). And it might not be required to repeat the typing, so an additional argument could be used to arrange that. So we get: `Clock[{1, StringLength@str, 1}, StringLength@str secPerLetter, 1]`

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries yeye, editing, thankx

Answer (score 7):

Implementation with `ScheduledTask`. When the `Type` button is pushed, a scheduled task is started that increases the display length of the temporary string `temp`. It can be paused (`Stop`) and continued (`Type` again).

```
text = StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "LoremIpsum"}], 120]

temp = ""; task = None; n = 0;
Row@{Button["Type", If[task =!= None, RemoveScheduledTask@task]; 
   task = RunScheduledTask[
     If[n > StringLength@text, RemoveScheduledTask@task; n = 0, 
      temp = StringTake[text, n++]], 0.01]],
  Button["Stop", If[task =!= None, RemoveScheduledTask@task]]}
Dynamic@temp
```

[image]